# Yum Install software-properties-common on EC2

Tags: linux, python, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to install software-properties-common on an EC2 micro instance and getting the following error:

```
$ sudo yum install software-properties-common
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
 amzn-main/latest                                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                                                                | 2.3 kB     00:00     
No package software-properties-common available.
```

Same result trying to install python-software-properties (which is same package for different OS version).

So I'm guessing that the `amzn-updates` and `amzn-main` package repositories don't contain either of these packages and I need to maybe [add a repository](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/add-repositories.html)?

Will report back after poking around a bit more. In the meantime, input more than welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is that `software-properties-common` is a package for managing packages installed with `Apt`, so since CentOS uses `Yum`, it's irrelevant anyway.